# Is there a max limit of code rows quantity inside doPost() in servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an Android application which connects to a Servlet.
Lately when I try to add code rows to the doPost() in the servlet (Almost all the program is written inside this method), and try to run the 
tomcat server I get the next error:

```
    0006a90: 00a4 b601 9519 14b6 0198 1914 b601 9ba7
    0006aa0: 007d 192c 1306 b5b6 0110 9900 69bb 0095
    0006ab0: 5913 019c b700 9919 04b6 00a0 b600 a43a
    0006ac0: 19b2 008f bb00 9559 1301 a0b7 0099 1919
    0006ad0: b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a52a b406 a919 19b9
    0006ae0: 0165 0200 3a0e 190e 04b9 01a2 0200 190e
    0006af0: 03b9 01a6 0200 b200 8f13 06b7 b600 a519
    0006b00: 0eb9 01ad 0100 57b2 008f 1306 b9b6 00a5
    0006b10: a700 0cb2 008f 1306 bbb6 00a5 2a13 014c
    0006b20: b801 4eb5 06bd b200 8f13 01b4 b600 a513
    0006b30: 01b6 3a17 2ab4 06bd 1917 b901 6502 003a
    0006b40: 0e19 0eb9 016b 0100 3a16 1916 b901 7101
    0006b50: 0057 b200 8f13 06bf b600 a52a 1916 04b9
    0006b60: 0183 0200 b501 bab2 008f 1306 c1b6 00a5
    0006b70: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 01be b700 992a b401
    0006b80: bab6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5 b200 8f13 01c0
    0006b90: b600 a513 01c2 3a17 2ab4 06bd 1917 b901
    0006ba0: 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 01c4 0100 57a7 014a
    0006bb0: 3a2c b200 8fbb 0095 5913 06c3 b700 9919
    0006bc0: 2cb6 01c9 b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a5b2 008f
    0006bd0: 1306 c5b6 00a5 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce
    0006be0: 0100 b200 8f13 06c7 b600 a519 0ec6 000a
    0006bf0: 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f 1306 c9b6 00a5
    0006c00: 2ab4 06a9 c600 0c2a b406 a9b9 01d0 0100
    0006c10: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 06cb b700 992a b406
    0006c20: a9b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a
    0006c30: b406 bdc6 000c 2ab4 06bd b901 d001 00b2
    0006c40: 008f bb00 9559 1306 cdb7 0099 2ab4 06bd
    0006c50: b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a716
    0006c60: 343a 2db2 008f 1306 c5b6 00a5 1916 c600
    0006c70: 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13 06c7 b600
    0006c80: a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f
    0006c90: 1306 c9b6 00a5 2ab4 06a9 c600 0c2a b406
    0006ca0: a9b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 06cb
    0006cb0: b700 992a b406 a9b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6
    0006cc0: 00a4 b600 a52a b406 bdc6 000c 2ab4 06bd
    0006cd0: b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1306 cdb7
    0006ce0: 0099 2ab4 06bd b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600
    0006cf0: a4b6 00a5 192d bfb2 008f 1306 c5b6 00a5
    0006d00: 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13
    0006d10: 06c7 b600 a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01
    0006d20: 00b2 008f 1306 c9b6 00a5 2ab4 06a9 c600
    0006d30: 0c2a b406 a9b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095
    0006d40: 5913 06cb b700 992a b406 a9b9 01d3 0100
    0006d50: b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a b406 bdc6 000c
    0006d60: 2ab4 06bd b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559
    0006d70: 1306 cdb7 0099 2ab4 06bd b901 d301 00b6
    0006d80: 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a715 0a2a 04b5 0076
    0006d90: b200 8f13 06cf b600 a513 06d1 3a04 2a13
    0006da0: 014c b801 4eb5 06d3 2d12 e615 1504 60b6
    0006db0: 0262 361c 2d15 1504 6015 1cb6 00ec 3a2c
    0006dc0: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 06d5 b700 9919 2cb6
    0006dd0: 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5 192c 1306 adb6 0110
    0006de0: 9900 8013 06af 3a17 2ab4 06d3 1917 b901
    0006df0: 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 016b 0100 3a16 1916
    0006e00: b901 7101 0057 1916 04b9 0177 0200 b806
    0006e10: b13a 18b2 008f bb00 9559 1306 d7b7 0099
    0006e20: 1918 b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a5bb 00df 592c
    0006e30: b900 b101 00b7 00e1 3a14 1914 bb00 9559
    0006e40: 1918 b803 e6b7 0099 12e6 b600 a0b6 00a4
    0006e50: b601 9519 14b6 0198 1914 b601 9ba7 0088
    0006e60: 192c 1306 b5b6 0110 9a00 0e19 2c13 06d9
    0006e70: b601 1099 0069 bb00 9559 1301 9cb7 0099
    0006e80: 1904 b600 a0b6 00a4 3a19 b200 8fbb 0095
    0006e90: 5913 01a0 b700 9919 19b6 00a0 b600 a4b6
    0006ea0: 00a5 2ab4 06d3 1919 b901 6502 003a 0e19
    0006eb0: 0e04 b901 a202 0019 0e03 b901 a602 00b2
    0006ec0: 008f 1306 dbb6 00a5 190e b901 ad01 0057
    0006ed0: b200 8f13 06dd b600 a5a7 000c b200 8f13
    0006ee0: 06df b600 a52a 1301 4cb8 014e b506 e1b2
    0006ef0: 008f 1301 b4b6 00a5 1301 b63a 172a b406
    0006f00: e119 17b9 0165 0200 3a0e 190e b901 6b01
    0006f10: 003a 1619 16b9 0171 0100 57b2 008f 1305
    0006f20: 90b6 00a5 2a19 1604 b901 8302 00b5 01ba
    0006f30: b200 8f13 06e3 b600 a5b2 008f bb00 9559
    0006f40: 1301 beb7 0099 2ab4 01ba b600 a0b6 00a4
    0006f50: b600 a5b2 008f 1301 c0b6 00a5 1301 c23a
    0006f60: 172a b406 e119 17b9 0165 0200 3a0e 190e
    0006f70: b901 c401 0057 a701 4a3a 2cb2 008f bb00
    0006f80: 9559 1306 e5b7 0099 192c b601 c9b6 00a0
    0006f90: b600 a4b6 00a5 b200 8f13 06e7 b600 a519
    0006fa0: 16c6 000a 1916 b901 ce01 00b2 008f 1306
    0006fb0: e9b6 00a5 190e c600 0a19 0eb9 01cf 0100
    0006fc0: b200 8f13 06eb b600 a52a b406 d3c6 000c
    0006fd0: 2ab4 06d3 b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559
    0006fe0: 1306 edb7 0099 2ab4 06d3 b901 d301 00b6
    0006ff0: 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 2ab4 06e1 c600 0c2a
    0007000: b406 e1b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913
    0007010: 06ef b700 992a b406 e1b9 01d3 0100 b601
    0007020: d6b6 00a4 b600 a5a7 126b 3a2d b200 8f13
    0007030: 06e7 b600 a519 16c6 000a 1916 b901 ce01
    0007040: 00b2 008f 1306 e9b6 00a5 190e c600 0a19
    0007050: 0eb9 01cf 0100 b200 8f13 06eb b600 a52a
    0007060: b406 d3c6 000c 2ab4 06d3 b901 d001 00b2
    0007070: 008f bb00 9559 1306 edb7 0099 2ab4 06d3
    0007080: b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 2ab4
    0007090: 06e1 c600 0c2a b406 e1b9 01d0 0100 b200
    00070a0: 8fbb 0095 5913 06ef b700 992a b406 e1b9
    00070b0: 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a519 2dbf
    00070c0: b200 8f13 06e7 b600 a519 16c6 000a 1916
    00070d0: b901 ce01 00b2 008f 1306 e9b6 00a5 190e
    00070e0: c600 0a19 0eb9 01cf 0100 b200 8f13 06eb
    00070f0: b600 a52a b406 d3c6 000c 2ab4 06d3 b901
    0007100: d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1306 edb7 0099
    0007110: 2ab4 06d3 b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6
    0007120: 00a5 2ab4 06e1 c600 0c2a b406 e1b9 01d0
    0007130: 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 06ef b700 992a
    0007140: b406 e1b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600
    0007150: a5a7 1141 2a04 b500 76b2 008f 1306 f1b6
    0007160: 00a5 2a13 014c b801 4eb5 06f3 1306 f53a
    0007170: 04bb 0095 5913 019c b700 9919 04b6 00a0
    0007180: b600 a43a 19b2 008f bb00 9559 1301 a0b7
    0007190: 0099 1919 b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a52a b406
    00071a0: f319 19b9 0236 0200 3a0d 190d b902 3a01
    00071b0: 0057 2a13 014c b801 4eb5 06f7 b200 8f13
    00071c0: 01b4 b600 a513 01b6 3a17 2ab4 06f7 1917
    00071d0: b901 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 016b 0100 3a16
    00071e0: 1916 b901 7101 0057 b200 8f13 06f9 b600
    00071f0: a52a 1916 04b9 0183 0200 b501 bab2 008f
    0007200: 1306 fbb6 00a5 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 01be
    0007210: b700 992a b401 bab6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5
    0007220: b200 8f13 01c0 b600 a513 01c2 3a17 2ab4
    0007230: 06f7 1917 b901 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 01c4
    0007240: 0100 57a7 014a 3a2c b200 8fbb 0095 5913
    0007250: 06fd b700 9919 2cb6 01c9 b600 a0b6 00a4
    0007260: b600 a5b2 008f 1306 ffb6 00a5 1916 c600
    0007270: 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13 0701 b600
    0007280: a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f
    0007290: 1307 03b6 00a5 2ab4 06f3 c600 0c2a b406
    00072a0: f3b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0705
    00072b0: b700 992a b406 f3b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6
    00072c0: 00a4 b600 a52a b406 f7c6 000c 2ab4 06f7
    00072d0: b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1307 07b7
    00072e0: 0099 2ab4 06f7 b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600
    00072f0: a4b6 00a5 a70f 9e3a 2db2 008f 1306 ffb6
    0007300: 00a5 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200
    0007310: 8f13 0701 b600 a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901
    0007320: cf01 00b2 008f 1307 03b6 00a5 2ab4 06f3
    0007330: c600 0c2a b406 f3b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb
    0007340: 0095 5913 0705 b700 992a b406 f3b9 01d3
    0007350: 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a b406 f7c6
    0007360: 000c 2ab4 06f7 b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00
    0007370: 9559 1307 07b7 0099 2ab4 06f7 b901 d301
    0007380: 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 192d bfb2 008f
    0007390: 1306 ffb6 00a5 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce
    00073a0: 0100 b200 8f13 0701 b600 a519 0ec6 000a
    00073b0: 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f 1307 03b6 00a5
    00073c0: 2ab4 06f3 c600 0c2a b406 f3b9 01d0 0100
    00073d0: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0705 b700 992a b406
    00073e0: f3b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a
    00073f0: b406 f7c6 000c 2ab4 06f7 b901 d001 00b2
    0007400: 008f bb00 9559 1307 07b7 0099 2ab4 06f7
    0007410: b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a70e
    0007420: 742a 04b5 0076 b200 8f13 0709 b600 a52a
    0007430: 1301 4cb8 014e b507 0b13 070d 3a04 bb00
    0007440: 9559 1301 9cb7 0099 1904 b600 a0b6 00a4
    0007450: 3a19 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 01a0 b700 9919
    0007460: 19b6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5 2ab4 070b 1919
    0007470: b902 3602 003a 0d19 0db9 023a 0100 572a
    0007480: 1301 4cb8 014e b507 0fb2 008f 1301 b4b6
    0007490: 00a5 1301 b63a 172a b407 0f19 17b9 0165
    00074a0: 0200 3a0e 190e b901 6b01 003a 1619 16b9
    00074b0: 0171 0100 57b2 008f 1307 11b6 00a5 2a19
    00074c0: 1604 b901 8302 00b5 01ba b200 8f13 0713
    00074d0: b600 a5b2 008f bb00 9559 1301 beb7 0099
    00074e0: 2ab4 01ba b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a5b2 008f
    00074f0: 1301 c0b6 00a5 1301 c23a 172a b407 0f19
    0007500: 17b9 0165 0200 3a0e 190e b901 c401 0057
    0007510: a701 4a3a 2cb2 008f bb00 9559 1307 15b7
    0007520: 0099 192c b601 c9b6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5
    0007530: b200 8f13 0717 b600 a519 16c6 000a 1916
    0007540: b901 ce01 00b2 008f 1307 19b6 00a5 190e
    0007550: c600 0a19 0eb9 01cf 0100 b200 8f13 071b
    0007560: b600 a52a b407 0bc6 000c 2ab4 070b b901
    0007570: d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1307 1db7 0099
    0007580: 2ab4 070b b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6
    0007590: 00a5 2ab4 070f c600 0c2a b407 0fb9 01d0
    00075a0: 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 071f b700 992a
    00075b0: b407 0fb9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600
    00075c0: a5a7 0cd1 3a2d b200 8f13 0717 b600 a519
    00075d0: 16c6 000a 1916 b901 ce01 00b2 008f 1307
    00075e0: 19b6 00a5 190e c600 0a19 0eb9 01cf 0100
    00075f0: b200 8f13 071b b600 a52a b407 0bc6 000c
    0007600: 2ab4 070b b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559
    0007610: 1307 1db7 0099 2ab4 070b b901 d301 00b6
    0007620: 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 2ab4 070f c600 0c2a
    0007630: b407 0fb9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913
    0007640: 071f b700 992a b407 0fb9 01d3 0100 b601
    0007650: d6b6 00a4 b600 a519 2dbf b200 8f13 0717
    0007660: b600 a519 16c6 000a 1916 b901 ce01 00b2
    0007670: 008f 1307 19b6 00a5 190e c600 0a19 0eb9
    0007680: 01cf 0100 b200 8f13 071b b600 a52a b407
    0007690: 0bc6 000c 2ab4 070b b901 d001 00b2 008f
    00076a0: bb00 9559 1307 1db7 0099 2ab4 070b b901
    00076b0: d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 2ab4 070f
    00076c0: c600 0c2a b407 0fb9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb
    00076d0: 0095 5913 071f b700 992a b407 0fb9 01d3
    00076e0: 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a5a7 0ba7 2a04
    00076f0: b500 76b2 008f 1307 21b6 00a5 2a13 014c
    0007700: b801 4eb5 0723 1307 253a 04bb 0095 5913
    0007710: 019c b700 9919 04b6 00a0 b600 a43a 19b2
    0007720: 008f bb00 9559 1301 a0b7 0099 1919 b600
    0007730: a0b6 00a4 b600 a52a b407 2319 19b9 0236
    0007740: 0200 3a0d 190d b902 3a01 0057 2a13 014c
    0007750: b801 4eb5 0727 b200 8f13 01b4 b600 a513
    0007760: 01b6 3a17 2ab4 0727 1917 b901 6502 003a
    0007770: 0e19 0eb9 016b 0100 3a16 1916 b901 7101
    0007780: 0057 b200 8f13 0729 b600 a52a 1916 04b9
    0007790: 0183 0200 b501 bab2 008f 1307 2bb6 00a5
    00077a0: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 01be b700 992a b401
    00077b0: bab6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5 b200 8f13 01c0
    00077c0: b600 a513 01c2 3a17 2ab4 0727 1917 b901
    00077d0: 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 01c4 0100 57a7 014a
    00077e0: 3a2c b200 8fbb 0095 5913 072d b700 9919
    00077f0: 2cb6 01c9 b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a5b2 008f
    0007800: 1307 2fb6 00a5 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce
    0007810: 0100 b200 8f13 0731 b600 a519 0ec6 000a
    0007820: 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f 1307 33b6 00a5
    0007830: 2ab4 0723 c600 0c2a b407 23b9 01d0 0100
    0007840: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0735 b700 992a b407
    0007850: 23b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a
    0007860: b407 27c6 000c 2ab4 0727 b901 d001 00b2
    0007870: 008f bb00 9559 1307 37b7 0099 2ab4 0727
    0007880: b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a70a
    0007890: 043a 2db2 008f 1307 2fb6 00a5 1916 c600
    00078a0: 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13 0731 b600
    00078b0: a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f
    00078c0: 1307 33b6 00a5 2ab4 0723 c600 0c2a b407
    00078d0: 23b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0735
    00078e0: b700 992a b407 23b9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6
    00078f0: 00a4 b600 a52a b407 27c6 000c 2ab4 0727
    0007900: b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1307 37b7
    0007910: 0099 2ab4 0727 b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600
    0007920: a4b6 00a5 192d bfb2 008f 1307 2fb6 00a5
    0007930: 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13
    0007940: 0731 b600 a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01
    0007950: 00b2 008f 1307 33b6 00a5 2ab4 0723 c600
    0007960: 0c2a b407 23b9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095
    0007970: 5913 0735 b700 992a b407 23b9 01d3 0100
    0007980: b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a b407 27c6 000c
    0007990: 2ab4 0727 b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559
    00079a0: 1307 37b7 0099 2ab4 0727 b901 d301 00b6
    00079b0: 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a708 da2a 04b5 0076
    00079c0: b200 8f13 0739 b600 a52a 1301 4cb8 014e
    00079d0: b507 3b13 0621 3a2c 1307 3d3a 172a b407
    00079e0: 3b19 17b9 0165 0200 3a0e 190e b901 6b01
    00079f0: 003a 1619 16b9 0171 0100 5719 1604 b901
    0007a00: 8302 003a 2cb2 008f bb00 9559 1307 3fb7
    0007a10: 0099 192c b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a513 0741
    0007a20: 3a04 bb00 9559 1302 96b7 0099 1904 b600
    0007a30: a013 04d1 b600 a0b6 00a4 3a19 b200 8fbb
    0007a40: 0095 5913 01a0 b700 9919 19b6 00a0 b600
    0007a50: a4b6 00a5 2ab4 073b 1919 b901 6502 003a
    0007a60: 0e19 0e04 192c b901 7f03 0019 0e05 04b9
    0007a70: 0212 0300 190e 04b9 01a2 0200 190e 03b9
    0007a80: 01a6 0200 190e b901 ad01 0057 2a13 014c
    0007a90: b801 4eb5 0743 b200 8f13 01b4 b600 a513
    0007aa0: 01b6 3a17 2ab4 0743 1917 b901 6502 003a
    0007ab0: 0e19 0eb9 016b 0100 3a16 1916 b901 7101
    0007ac0: 0057 b200 8f13 0745 b600 a52a 1916 04b9
    0007ad0: 0183 0200 b501 bab2 008f 1307 47b6 00a5
    0007ae0: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 01be b700 992a b401
    0007af0: bab6 00a0 b600 a4b6 00a5 b200 8f13 01c0
    0007b00: b600 a513 01c2 3a17 2ab4 0743 1917 b901
    0007b10: 6502 003a 0e19 0eb9 01c4 0100 57a7 014a
    0007b20: 3a2c b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0749 b700 9919
    0007b30: 2cb6 01c9 b600 a0b6 00a4 b600 a5b2 008f
    0007b40: 1307 4bb6 00a5 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce
    0007b50: 0100 b200 8f13 074d b600 a519 0ec6 000a
    0007b60: 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f 1307 4fb6 00a5
    0007b70: 2ab4 073b c600 0c2a b407 3bb9 01d0 0100
    0007b80: b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0751 b700 992a b407
    0007b90: 3bb9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a
    0007ba0: b407 43c6 000c 2ab4 0743 b901 d001 00b2
    0007bb0: 008f bb00 9559 1307 53b7 0099 2ab4 0743
    0007bc0: b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a706
    0007bd0: c43a 2db2 008f 1307 4bb6 00a5 1916 c600
    0007be0: 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13 074d b600
    0007bf0: a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01 00b2 008f
    0007c00: 1307 4fb6 00a5 2ab4 073b c600 0c2a b407
    0007c10: 3bb9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095 5913 0751
    0007c20: b700 992a b407 3bb9 01d3 0100 b601 d6b6
    0007c30: 00a4 b600 a52a b407 43c6 000c 2ab4 0743
    0007c40: b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559 1307 53b7
    0007c50: 0099 2ab4 0743 b901 d301 00b6 01d6 b600
    0007c60: a4b6 00a5 192d bfb2 008f 1307 4bb6 00a5
    0007c70: 1916 c600 0a19 16b9 01ce 0100 b200 8f13
    0007c80: 074d b600 a519 0ec6 000a 190e b901 cf01
    0007c90: 00b2 008f 1307 4fb6 00a5 2ab4 073b c600
    0007ca0: 0c2a b407 3bb9 01d0 0100 b200 8fbb 0095
    0007cb0: 5913 0751 b700 992a b407 3bb9 01d3 0100
    0007cc0: b601 d6b6 00a4 b600 a52a b407 43c6 000c
    0007cd0: 2ab4 0743 b901 d001 00b2 008f bb00 9559
    0007ce0: 1307 53b7 0099 2ab4 0743 b901 d301 00b6
    0007cf0: 01d6 b600 a4b6 00a5 a705 9a2a 04b5 0076
    0007d00: b200 8f13 0755 b600 a52a 1301 4cb8 014e
    0007d10: b507 5713 0759 3a04 bb00 9559 1301 9cb7
    0007d20: 0099 1904 b600 a0b6 00a4 3a19 b200 8fbb
    0007d30: 0095 5913 01a0 b700 9919 19b6 00a0 b600
    0007d40: a4b6 00a5 2ab4 0757 1919 b902 3602 003a
    0007d50: 0d19 0db9 023a 0100 572a 1301 4cb8 014e
    0007d60: b507 5bb2 008f 1301 b4b6 00a5 1301 b63a
    0007d70: 172a b407 5b19 17b9 0165 0200 3a0e 190e
    0007d80: b901 6b01 003a 1619 16b9 0171 0100 57b2
    0007d90: 008f 1307 5db6 00a5 2a19 1604 b901 8302
    0007da0: 00b5 01ba b200 8f13 075f b600 a5b2 008f
    0007db0: bb00 9559 1301 beb7 0099 2ab4 01ba b600
{Object[#1],Object[#196],Object[#178],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#214],Object[#571],Object[#364],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer,Object[#370],Object[#214],Top,Top,Top,Integer,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#214]},{})
        full_frame(@1267,{Object[#1],Object[#196],Object[#178],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#214],Object[#571],Object[#364],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer,Object[#370],Object[#214],Object[#214],Top,Top,Integer,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#214]},{})
        same_frame(@1275)
        same_frame(@1283)
        same_frame(@1302)
```

---  THERE ARE LOT OF THESE ERORR ROWS SO I CUT IT ---

```
{Object[#1],Object[#196],Object[#178],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#214],Object[#571],Object[#364],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer,Object[#370],Object[#214],Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Top,Object[#214],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#906],Object[#942],Top,Object[#950]},{})
        same_frame(@11566)
        full_frame(@11653
        full_frame(@22992{Object[#1],Object[#196],Object[#178],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#214],Object[#571],Object[#364],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer,Object[#370]},{Integer,Integer})
        same_frame_extended(@33615)
        full_frame(@33653,{Object[#1],Object[#196],Object[#178],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Object[#214],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Object[#214],Object[#571],Object[#364],Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer,Top,Integer},{Object[#458]})
        same_frame(@33682)

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more

    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    מאי 20, 2015 10:21:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Suprisingly , when I remove the added code **OR ANY FORMER**  code,
the tomcat is running well. 
Is it possible there is a limit to how many rows one can adds to doPost() inside servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Java are you running on the server side? There are, apparently, some limitations on the amount of bytecode that can be generated for any method: see [this answer on a slightly related question on another StackExchange site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/66535) for example. Note, however, that on Java 5 and above, such limitations have been extended so much that you should never worry to bump into them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. in my check: java.runtime.version=1.7.0_71-b14. I found it by System.getProperty("java.runtime.version". Is that the version you ment to?

Comment: @Eliran yep. So, it seems the case I described is hardly yours, because the limit on the bytecode generated per method in Java > 1.5 is 4 GB.